# Know when an order has been paid

Tags: 7, commerce

I need to export some order data to a CSV file. One field is the date (d-m-Y) when the order has been paid. I have search in hook_commerce_*, in the database, but I have not find anything that can help me. Is this data saved in the database, or I need to create a rule that saves this information when the order is payed in full the first time?

Comment: Please avoid adding signatures, and thanks in your questions. They will be removed.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to do this in the past. I exported with a View, and used a *Representative payment transaction* relationship, using *Commerce Payment Transaction: Status* as the representative sort criteria. Then I just added the *Commerce Payment Transaction: Created date* field. Assuming that the entire payment is done in one go, I think this method's sound.

Comment: Hi, I can not know if one user create today and pay tomorrow, so I need the tommorow date. Thanks however.

Comment: @ZioBudda Yes, that's what this method will give you. Note that the field we're using is not the _order_ created date but the _payment transaction_ created date.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this information is stored in the database.

Look at the database for a table called `commerce_payment_transaction`. Here it is stored the transaction information of the attempted payments. The column `status` will tell you if the payment was successfull and in the `created` field you have the payment date (in POSIX time).

That said, using Views and [Views data export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) could be another solution.

Comment: Hi, I had see that table, but in my case it is empty. But I have payed (my order is in completed state) via paypal sandbox site. Why my table is empty ?

Comment: I don't know, my table is not empty. Even when I pay with a 'no payment required' method this table is filled. Are you sure you are looking at the right database?

Comment: Hi, I have resolved. There was a problem in the reply of paypal (my site is under http access). Tnx.